# Drawing rhombuses in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am basically trying to draw rhombuses using number signs and dots.  My code doesn't do what it is supposed to do once it reaches the specified size. If the size is 5 each line should have 5 characters.  Provided that the given size is greater then 0 the program should always print 1 number sign for the first line and 1 dot on each side. On the left of the number signs the code should print the numbers of dots which is size-#of diamonds/ 2 and it should print the same number of dots to the right of the number signs. Eventually when the number of #signs reaches the specified size it should start subtracting 2 from the # of number signs until the #of number signs is equal to 1/ or is no longer a positive number. The number signs will form a diamond. Also how can I check input to make sure it is a odd, positive number.

```
size = 5
diamonds = 1
dots = size - 1
count = 2

while count != size:
    print (dots/2)*('.') + diamonds*('#') + (dots/2)*('.')
    if diamonds == size:
        break
    diamonds += 2  
    dots -= dots / 2
    count += 1


while count == size:
    diamonds -= 2
    print (dots)*('.') + diamonds*('#') + (dots)*('.')
    dots += 2
```

Comment: can you post the current output and the expected output?

Comment: and what should be printed if size is not an odd number?

Comment: Invalid input if size is not an odd number

Answer (score 0):

From whatever I could understand, the following should do the work for you.

```
size = 5
diamonds = 1
dots = size - 1
count = 2

while count != size:
    print '.'*(dots/2) + '#'*diamonds + '.'*(dots/2)
    if diamonds == size:
        break
    diamonds += 2
    dots -= dots / 2
    count += 1

while dots < size - 1:
    diamonds -= 2
    dots += 2
    print '.'*(dots/2) + '#'*diamonds + '.'*(dots/2)
        count -= 1
```

The output was...

```
..#..
.###.
#####
.###.
..#..
```

As for the 2nd question, i.e. "how can I check input to make sure it is a odd, positive number", you could do

```
>>>given_number = input()
3                         # I give input as say 3
>>>given_number
3
>>>given_number%2 == 1    # Remainder when divided by 2 is 1 (thus odd number)
True                      # True, since 3 is an odd number
>>>given_number >= 0      # To check if number is positive
True                      # 3 is both odd & positive
```

Thus, to check if number is odd & positive, you should do

```
if number%2 == 1 and number >= 0:
    # do something
```